# urllib2.urlopen it uses time.sleep?

Tags: python

I create an automate translate for a chat in-a-game. I can't understand why when it call:

```
res = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
```

there is like a use of time.sleep because the game it's freezing for about 100 milleseconds. I have look into urllib2 but there is no use of sleep, I really don't get it, does someone have same problem? Or someone have any ideea how can I solve?

Comment: The HTTP request is probably blocking your main thread, take a look at [concurrent code execution  in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrency.html).

Comment: Ty for the info. I solve by passing to thread